# How can I create a simple count down timer in HH:MM:SS and show them in a Lazy Column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, countdowntimer

I was learning jetpack compose and I can't seem to get my head around how to create a simple countDownTimer. What I want to do is create a countDownTimer that accepts three inputs from the user (hours, minutes, and seconds), and then when I click on the start button I want to show the timer in a LazyColomun . Any link that you think might help me understand this is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes to create a Countdown Timer:

input: a date

```
val time = (timerDate.time).minus(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(time) }
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = timer) {
      if (timer > 0) {
          delay(1000L)
          timer -= 1000L
       }
     }
  val secMilSec: Long = 1000
  val minMilSec = 60 * secMilSec
  val hourMilSec = 60 * minMilSec
  val dayMilSec = 24 * hourMilSec
  val hours = (time % dayMilSec / hourMilSec).toInt()
  val minutes = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec / minMilSec).toInt()
  val seconds = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec % minMilSec / secMilSec).toInt()

Text(text = String.format(" %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

### General Understanding

The most basic form of a timer, counts in seconds or milliseconds. Even if you ask for hours, minutes and seconds from the user you should get that all converted to seconds/milliseconds and start the timer on that basis.

For Example

- Hours = 3
- Minutes = 15
- Seconds = 20

all converted to seconds

- Hours = 3(hr) = 10800 seconds
- Minutes = 15(min) = 15 * 60 = 900 seconds
- Seconds = 20(sec) = 20 seconds

so your timer should count down from hr + min + sec = 11720 seconds

You simply do a conversion from seconds/milliseconds to the format you want to display the elapsed time in whenever you want to display (your refresh rate)

### External Article

The below article should do what you want.

[Let’s Make a Countdown Timer app using Android Compose](https://proandroiddev.com/lets-make-a-countdown-timer-app-using-android-compose-762cbdd16f3f)